# tags: metadata and metadata-api -- thoughts

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

what do you think, should these be merged and synonymized?

[metadata](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata)

[metadata-api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metadata-api)

Answer (score 5):

I can think of uses for a 'metadata' tag that aren't related to the API, so I don't think they should necessarily be merged. I'm happy to quietly retag questions as I notice they are incorrect.

Comment: I looked at the currently tagged, and there is some confusion IMO

Comment: Retag the ones you think are incorrect.

Comment: that's easy, I was thinking for future ones

Comment: I agree with metadaddy, they are not the same. If there is confusion, we can take it up as our responsibility as community to clear that up. Labeling them both under a single tag won't achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that they should be merged as they represent different topics; metadata describes your org and the API is how you manipulate it.

One problem I see is that neither tag has a description, which could be contributing to the problems.

Comment: Suggest some descriptions - just adding wiki excerpts to the tags could be enough.